# Can I overfly Canada without a passport?

Tags: usa, regulations, canada

Can an American pilot without a passport fly in Canadian airspace as long as they don't land in Canada?

Comment: What does FAA (a US agency) have to do with Canadian overflight regulations?

Comment: @ZeissIkon the pilot would be leaving and re-entering US airspace.

Comment: Even that is Customs and/or ICE, not FAA.

Comment: @ZeissIkon would this be better on Law SE?

Comment: Likely it's okay here since it's relevant mainly to aviation, you just need to fix the tags.  I see you've done that.  Should be answerable now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether you are a pilot or not doesn't matter, passports and visas are not required to overfly the USA, Canada and most places in the world. A case in point, if you are flying from most of the continental USA to Alaska you will fly over Canada at some point but you are not required to bring a passport as it's considered a domestic flight.

It would still make sense to bring your passport though, if you do end up landing for one reason or another it will come in handy.

Comment: One doesn't even have to fly from the _East coast_ to overfly Canada on the way to ANC, FAI or other Alaskan airports! Us Midwesterners get to go through Canadian airspace on our way up there, too. I've not brought my passport (as a paying passenger, not a pilot) on any of my trips to AK.

Comment: It's a good point @FreeMan, I've modified it to talk about the continental US.

Comment: _Puts on pedant cap_, gcmap.com doesn't show Canadian overflight for LAX-ANC. :D But this is accurate for about 99% of the US, so I'll just shut up now. ;)

Comment: If you please @FreeMan :)